# Pandas read_html can't be changed to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Trying to use Pandas read_html feature to web scrap a table from fbref. Am capable of getting the data but want to save the data as a csv file.

Am getting the Error 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

The Python Code is:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/comps/Big5/Big-5-European-Leagues-Stats#big5_table')
raw_data.to_csv('Top_5.csv')
print(raw_data)
```

I have tried to change raw data to a DataFrame first and then save to csv, when doing that I get an error of having to reshape to 2-d.

Answer (score 1):

`read_html()` returns a list of tables found on the page, since a page can contain multiple tables.

In this case, the first and only table is the one you're interested in.

You can fix this like so:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/comps/Big5/Big-5-European-Leagues-Stats#big5_table')
raw_data[0].to_csv('soccer.csv')
print(raw_data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `pd.read_html()` returns a list of `DataFrame`s, not just one of them.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/comps/Big5/Big-5-European-Leagues-Stats#big5_table')[0]
raw_data.to_csv('Top_5.csv')
print(raw_data)
```